# Count number of instances of object type in OrderedSet

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an `OrderedSet` of objects of different types. Let's call them a mix of `Apple`'s and `Orange`'s for simplicity.

To count the number of `Oranges` in the set, is there a simpler solution than the following?

```
number_of_oranges = 0
for fruit in basket:
    if isinstance(fruit, Orange):
        number_of_oranges += 1
```

I could also use a `defaultdict(int)` but this doesn't look a whole lot nicer and I *only* need the number of `Orange`'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `True` is `1`:

```
sum(isinstance(fruit, Orange) for fruit in basket)
```